# How to pull real time data to excel FYERS login

Tags: livefyre

I want to make view real-time data from FYERS using access token. All NSE,NFO and equity

I m trying to write python code for this. But error found in fyersmodel. How to correct it? I have also try
“pip install fyersmodel”
Where I m wrong could not understand. I m not good for writing python programs.